# How to utilize intermediate results of a tensorflow estimator?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

This question has bothered me several days. I'm using an RNN model on machine translation, and the model is implemented using an estimator. Now I want to do some operation on some intermediate tensors of every RNN step. I mainly want to have these tensors weighted. How could I fetch these tensors?

Comment: Do you want to print these intermediate values, use the values within TensorFlow (e.g. weight and feed to the next step), or to get the value for use in Python outside of TensorFlow?

Comment: The later. Simply, I have a variant in Python, and I want to multiply it with the value of a tensor, then feed the tensor with the new value, then let tf continue. I don't know is that possible? I've tried to print these values, but these tensors are in a while_loop so I can't use session to run them.

Comment: [py_func](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func) may be a reasonable option in that case. It will allow you to modify intermediate values as Numpy arrays and return them. You may want to define a gradient depending on what you're doing.

Comment: OK. I will look into this function. thx!